# Highlight a word in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

```
    function highlight(container,what) {
    var content = container.innerHTML,
        pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','g'),
        replaceWith = '$1<span style="background-color:red">$2</span>$3',
        highlighted = content.replace(pattern,replaceWith);
    return (container.innerHTML = highlighted) !== content;
 }
```

Above is the function written to highlight a specific word in the whole web page.

I am using it is

```
 highlight(document.body,"the");
```

And it works. If it is found any word, it makes it red background. The problem now is, once I run the functions, the javascript stops working on web pages.

Can someone help me to sort the problem. My guess is that the regex have issues. I am new to regex.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the actual function highlight() run more than once?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld only once after the page got loaded

Comment: How does your actual call to the function look like?

Comment: why dont you just replace the word only like new RegExp(what,'g');

Comment: Have you tried looking into something like https://github.com/NYTimes/Emphasis

Comment: Several issues I see: 1) there can be several `the` in-between `>` and `<`, and you will only replace one, 2) the `[^<.]*` will choke on a substring that contains literal periods as `.` inside the character class is a literal period. Did you take a look at *possible duplicate...*?